# STM32,Reading ADC Value and Transmitting using UART (HAL Library)

Tags: c, stm32, uart, adc, hal

I am new user of STM32(L476RG).I've done some work with Arduino so far. Now,I want to read ADC Value and transmit this value with UART. I setup hardware part and initial software configuration part. I want to know,  this part of code in while loop is correct?

```
if (HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000000) == HAL_OK)
{
    ADCValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
    sprintf(str, "%d", ADCValue);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,ADCValue,1,100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you call`HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1)` before entering the while loop.
Basically it is OK to call you code in a `while` loop, but I have some remarks.

Make sure that `ADCValue` variable is `uint32_t` or at least `uin16_t` as the [return value](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/2f/71/ba/b8/75/54/47/cf/DM00105879.pdf/files/DM00105879.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105879.pdf) of `HAL_ADC_GetValue` is `uint32_t`.  If the ADC's resolution is above 8 bit then 1 byte won't be enough to store the result.

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Transmit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout);
```

The `HAL_UART_Transmit` expects an `uint8_t*` as a second parameter, given your code you pass a simple variable. You should use the `&` operator before `ADCValue` and cast it to `uint8_t*`. Also it only sends 1 byte in your code, based on the third parameter. If `ADCValue` is `uint32_t` then you should modify this parameter to 4. Also note that you send raw byte value and not ASCII. All in all:

```
uint32_t ADCValue;

if (HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 1000000) == HAL_OK)
{
    ADCValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
    sprintf(str, "%d", ADCValue);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)(&ADCValue), 4, 100);
}
```

`(&ADCValue)` returns the address of `ADCValue` which is an `uint32_t*` so it should be casted to `uint8_t*` when passing to `HAL_UART_Transmit`. And as an `uint32_t` is 4 byte, third param should be 4.

If you want to send the `str` you should calculate its correct length before sending as well.

By the way here is an ADC example from this [STM32 HAL ADC Tutorial](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/stm32/adc/).

```
uint32_t g_ADCValue;    
int g_MeasurementNumber;


int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    ConfigureADC();

    HAL_ADC_Start(&g_AdcHandle);
    for (;;)
    {
        if (HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&g_AdcHandle, 1000000) == HAL_OK)
        {
            g_ADCValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&g_AdcHandle);
            g_MeasurementNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now, I am reading adc value,but when I used IF Statement in sample code,ADC Value wasn't read. Can you explain function of HAL_ADC_PollForConversion() ?

Answer (score -1):

What I did as the simplest working solution was to force an ADC reset:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef stat = HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 900);

if (stat != HAL_OK)  {
    HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
}
```

This should be executed earlier than just before GetValue, I had improper action then.

P.S. Sorry for poor visibility

Slightly more elegant would be stopping after GetValue function, yet I left this code as properly working.